PyQt5 QTimeEdit but with start and end time
Is it possible to create some kind of QTimeEdit but with a start and end time, something like HH:mm - HH:mm? I want to put it in a table just like the QTimeEdit.
I already tried to set the format of a normal QTimeEdit to 'HH:mm - HH:mm' but then the hour and minute value for both hours is the same. I also tried using two QTimeEdits next to each other but I want to use it in one input field. The last thing I tried was customizing a QLineEdit with an inputmask but this still lets me use 99:99 which isn't an hour. And I want the behaviour as close to the QTimeEdit as possible, so the cursorshape(it changes when I use the inputmask for some reason) has to stay the same and the selecting and typing rules should apply. what I mean is when I enter the custom input field the hour characters of the first time should be selected and if I type 5 for example it should go to the following minute part and select that. I tried but cannot find something like this anywhere on the internet so if anyone here could help me that would be great.

Setting the format is useless, as it obviously won't create a different time object (how would you access it?). While not completely impossible, it may be done by subclassing QAbstractSpinBox (as "fixing" QTimeEdit with a subclass would be probably more difficult), but that's pretty advanced stuff: if you don't know how to set a cursor yet, the above is out of your current experience. So, instead of complicating things, why don't you just use two QTimeEdit placed side by side? If you want to treat them as a single widget, then use a QWidget as container and set an horizontal layout for it.

Using two time-edits isn't completely simple either, since it may be desirable for the min/max times to be dynamically adjusted to prevent invalid time ranges (i.e. start > end or end < start). This can sometimes make editing an existing range a little tricky for the user if the new range falls outside the old range.

@ekhumoro But validating the time range would be necessary in any case, wouldn't it? Besides, having a single time edit would display the arrows for both, making it a bit counter intuitive considering UX: it's not like a QDateTimeEdit with many fields, in which the context is consistent (the same datetime object). I'm not saying that having 2 QTimeEdits is simple, but it certainly is much easier than trying to "fix" a QTimeEdit or creating a QAbstractSpinBox from scratch. For starters, there's the whole text input validation issue that would also need to consider the time range problem.

@musicamante The point is to entirely eliminate the extra validation step by automatically adjusting the min/max (thus creating a better UX). Also, I did not suggest a custom editor would be preferrable - in fact, I think a single input field could be quite fiddly and unintuitive to use. I was merely pointing out that it's not just a matter of putting two time-edits side-by-side. I suspect most users would be much more familiar with separate start and end fields, but it does require a little bit of extra work to get the two fields to play nicely with each other.
